# How to get the data of multiple cities using openweathermap api in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, openweathermap

I am new in angularjs, i want to get that data of multiple cities in angularjs.

Here is code.:

```
var app = angular.module('jsbin', []);    
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($http) {

                          var vm = this;
                          var vm1 = this;                              
                          var URL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily';

                          var request = {
                            method: 'GET',
                            url: URL,
                            params: {
                               q:'',
                              mode: 'json',
                              units: 'imperial',
                              cnt: '7',
                              appid: '4e1869d8da618fde99e84483*******'
                            }                              
                           };

                          $http(request)
                            .then(function(response) {
                              vm.data = response.data.list  ;
                              console.log(response.data);
                            }).
                            catch(function(response) {
                              vm.data = response.data;
                            });
});
```

Comment: So what is the problem? You already know how to do it.

Comment: But here i am getting data of only one city but i want data of more than one city.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
var URL = http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=524901,703448,2643743&units=metric
```

Source: http://openweathermap.org/current#severalid

EDIT:

If the endpoint doesn't cut it for you, you might have to use $q.all to execute multiple `'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily'` in parallel

Comment: Through this way , we can't get the data of multiple cities.

Comment: @Jverma make more one request per city?

Comment: Thankyou @Chris , but how to make more than one request per city?

Answer (score 0):

I see that OpenWeatherMap deleted for some reason this endpoint from docs, but not from the API itself.

Right now the working API call for several cities by id looks like this.

```js
var URL = http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=524901,703448,2643743&units;=metric&appid={API_KEY}
```

Found the [docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20210122004654/https://openweathermap.org/current#severalid) regarding this request only in web archive in January 2021.